# How can we store data securely in google when developing Gmail addon using Google app script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace, gmail-addons

I am creating a Gmail addon, my doubt was how can I save some secure and confidential information on Google side so that I can use it later in my code. Does Google provide some kind of secured storage mechanism?

Comment: What do you mean by secure storage? Are you looking for something encrypted at rest that Google employees can't easily get to? There is nothing like that. You could use the Google Cloud key manager to get an encryption key, but then you have a new problem, you would need to store the refresh token for a service account and then you need secure storage again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're talking about Google Cloud, you can check this documentation about [Local File Storage Security](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/addlhelp/SecurityandPrivacyConsiderations#local-file-storage-security).

Also, Apps Script offers [Cache Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/) that allows you to access a cache for short term storage of data:

- Public caches are for things that are not dependent on which user is accessing your script.
- Private caches are for things which are user-specific, like settings or recent activity.

Answer (score 5):

You can use app script's PropertiesService, it allows to store some unique information for scripts, attached to the script itself or the files the script is bound to. [This site](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/properties/properties-service) provides further explanation and examples on how to use the service.

Comment: the question specified gmail addons (apps script) - this is the correct answer.